# Kubernetes Argo workflows are failing with psp-readonlyrootfilesystem error

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, kubernetes-security, argo, podsecuritypolicy

I've the following argo workflow which has `securityContext` added.
After running it, it's failing with ReadOnlyRootFileSystem error as mentioned below.

Here is the workflow yaml.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: hello-world-
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay
  templates:
  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["hello world"]
      securityContext:
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
```

and the error is as below:

```
Warning  WorkflowNodeError  17s  workflow-controller  Error node hello-world-tcdbg: admission webhook "validation.gatekeeper.sh" denied the request: [psp-readonlyrootfilesystem] only read-only root filesystem container is allowed: wait

[psp-readonlyrootfilesystem] only read-only root filesystem container is allowed: init
```

Am I using securityContext in wrong position or am I missing anything? what's the fix for it?

Comment: Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using init containers in the yaml file as :

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: init-container-
spec:
  entrypoint: init-container-example
  templates:
  - name: init-container-example
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["echo", "bye"]
      securityContext: 
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      volumeMounts:
      - name: foo
        mountPath: /foo
    initContainers:
    - name: hello
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["echo", "hello"]
      mirrorVolumeMounts: true
  volumes:
    - name: foo
      emptyDir: {}
```

**Note**: readOnlyRootFilesystem: true that this field cannot be set when spec.os.name is windows.

For more information follow this [yaml](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/5815#issuecomment-802941158) for any changes and modifications.